# private props in ES6 don't work with WeakMap

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have created the following class:

```
import Confidence from 'confidence';

import manifest from './manifest';
import criteria from './criteria';

const privateProps = new WeakMap();

class Configuration {

    constructor() {
        privateProps(this, { store: new Confidence.Store(manifest) });
    }

    getKey(key) {
        return privateProps.get(this).store.key(key, criteria);
    }

    getMeta(key) {
        return privateProps.get(this).store.meta(key, criteria);
    }
}

let configuration = new Configuration();
export default configuration;
```

in order to make `store` props private since in ES6 there is no chance to have private props so far. Unfortunately transpling with babel I get this error:

```
privateProps(this, { store: new _confidence2['default'].Store(_manifes

TypeError: object is not a function
```

Any idea where is the mistake?

Comment: `WeakMap` objects are no functions… why are you *calling* `privateProps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `privateProps` (a `WeakMap` instance) is not a function.

You probably meant:

```
privateProps.set(this, { store: new Confidence.Store(manifest) });
```